# Can´t parse JSON with AlamoFire and SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am stuck with parsing JSON with `AlamoFire` and `SwiftyJSON` for iOS. I have a JSON such as this one:

```
[{"id":23561,"name":"RFI - Persan Ø±Ø§Ø¯ÛŒÙˆ ØµØ¯Ø§ÛŒ ÙØ±Ø§Ù†Ø³Ù‡ ÙØ§Ø±Ø³ÛŒ","country":"FR","image":{"url":null,"thumb":{"url":null}},"slug":"rfi-persan-Ø±Ø§Ø¯ÛŒÙˆ-ØµØ¯Ø§ÛŒ-ÙØ±Ø§Ù†Ø³Ù‡-ÙØ§Ø±Ø³ÛŒ","website":"rfi","twitter":"","facebook":"","categories":[{"id":21,"title":"News","description":"","slug":"news","ancestry":"4"}],"streams":[{"stream":"http://rfi-persan.scdn.arkena.com/rfienpersan.mp3","bitrate":0,"content_type":"audio/mpeg","status":1}],"created_at":"2016-01-12T07:52:08+01:00","updated_at":"2016-08-02T01:52:50+02:00"}]
```

This is what I´ve tried so far, but doesn't work:

```
func loadSomeJSONData() {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://example.com/json/")
            .responseJSON { (_, _, data, _) in
                let json = JSON(data!)
                if let Name = json["name"].string {
                    println("name: \(firstName)") // Name should equal "RFI"
                }
        }
    }
```

But for some reason it doesn't get name from json object.

Thank you very much!

Comment: what are u getting in log?

Comment: What are you get in the console when you do the `println` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json is `Array` not `Dictionary`, so access the json this way

```
if let arr = json.arrayObject as? [[String:AnyObject]] { 
    if let name = arr[0]["name"] as? String {
        println("name: \(name)") // Name should equal "RFI"
    }
}
```

Comment: One tip also access other object like same but be sure that `image`,`categories` and `streams` also are array.